# Representation of Number in hexal system

Tags: number-systems

A number written as $213$ in quadral system (number system with base $4$) will be
represented in hexal system (number system with base $6$) as:

(A) $23$

(B) $39$

(C) $103$

(D) $303$

Comment: Is that a question? What have you tried?

Comment: Transform 213 into base 10 and then the new number in base 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2*16 + 1*4 + 3*1 = 39
1*36 + 0*6 + 3*1 = 39
So the answer is C